# Launching WebDriver from a servlet.java throws exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I prepare a web interface that I could launch the WebDriver. I used servlet.java. I'm using JBoss application server, when I try to run it I receive the following exception

> 13:39:40,779 ERROR [[ArikTest]] Servlet.service() for servlet ArikTest threw exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
>   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
>   at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
>   at ArikTest.doGet(ArikTest.java:47)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
>   (ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
>   (ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke
>   (SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
>   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke
>   (CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process
>   (Http11Protocol.java:583)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

UPDATE in response to @xeranos:

Thanks for the quick reply, For your question, By the way I am not using maven. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Now if I choose right click --> run as java application.

Result: running fine, no problem

BUT when I try to run it from a web application here is an example:

```
//servlet that receive a submit from a JSP page and i want the webdriver to start

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response)

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 

}
```

I got the above exception, I used the JBOSS application server and I try to build a JSPnpage that with a click of a button the automation will start.

Is it possible? Am I getting this error because I'm trying to run it above the Jboss server?

Comment: I couldnt find the answer over the web, please helppppp.. it is possible to launch the webdriver (selenium2) through a java application BUT when i try to run it "on a server" on Jboss i receive exceptions . am i missing something ?

Comment: I'm also trying same... getting same error... anyone havin solution for this

Comment: I have edited the information from your answer into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) when creating Selenium project? Because it looks like you have problems with dependencies. All information you need for creating basic Selenium project can be founded on [official documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html).

> The easiest way to set up a Selenium 2.0 Java project is to use Maven. Maven will download the Java bindings (the Selenium 2.0 Java client library) and all its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not really have anything to do with testing.  You need to find someone who can tell you how to include the Selenium client pieces in a war (or ear?) file for JBoss.  Perhaps you should try posting your question at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).